# Copy file from assets to folder on the sdcard fails

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, tesseract, mkdir

I am using tesseract OCR in my app (Spl!t). When I launch the app from Eclipse to my phone, eng.traineddata is copied into /storage/emulated/0/Pictures/Receipts/tessdata/. But when I installed the app from the market, the eng.traineddata file is not copied into the folder. Is there something wrong with my code?

> ```
>   private File getOutputPhotoFile() {
>       directory = new File(
>               Environment
>                       .getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES),
>               "Receipts");
>       dataPath = directory.getAbsolutePath();
>       if (!directory.exists()) {
>           directory.mkdirs();
>           Toast.makeText(Trans_List.this, "Receipts Folder Created", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
>           File tessDir = new File(directory, "tessdata");
>           if (!tessDir.exists()) {
>               tessDir.mkdirs();
>           Toast.makeText(Trans_List.this, "Tessdata Folder Created",  Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
>               File trainingData = new File(tessDir, "eng.traineddata");
>               if(!trainingData.exists())
>                   new CopyLibrary().execute(LANG);
>           }
>       }
>       String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyMMdd_HHmmss")
>               .format(new Date());
>       return new File(directory.getPath() + File.separator + "Receipt_"
>               + timeStamp + ".jpg");
>   }   
>
> private class CopyLibrary extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {
>
>   private void copyFile(InputStream in, OutputStream out)
>           throws IOException {
>       byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
>       int read;
>       while ((read = in.read(buffer)) != -1)
>           out.write(buffer, 0, read);
>   }
>
>   @Override
>   protected Void doInBackground(String... s) {
>       AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();
>       String[] files = null;
>       try {
>           files = assetManager.list("");
>       } catch (IOException e) {
>           Log.e("Spl!t", "Failed to get asset file list.");
>       }
>       for (String filename : files) {
>       InputStream in = null;
>           OutputStream out = null;
>           try {
>               in = assetManager.open(filename);
>               File outFile = new File(dataPath + File.separator
>                       + "tessdata" + File.separator, LANG
>                       + ".traineddata");
>               out = new FileOutputStream(outFile);
>               copyFile(in, out);
>               in.close();
>               in = null;
>               out.flush();
>               out.close();
>               Toast.makeText(Trans_List.this, "Tessdata copied", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
>               out = null;
>           } catch (IOException e) {
>               Log.e(TAG, "Failed to copy asset file");
>           }
>       }
>       return null;
>   }
> }
> ```

Comment: "need to create the datapath /pictures/receipts/tessdata/eng.trainededdata" -- that is not possible, as you cannot create new directories off of the filesystem root (`/`), except perhaps on a rooted device.

Comment: @CommonsWare My phone is rooted but I am using .getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES) which is creating the directory under /storage/emulated/0/pictures/ . Is this the root folder?

Comment: "Is this the root folder" -- no, but you will not that `/storage/emulated/0/pictures/` is not `/pictures/receipts/tessdata/eng.trainededdata`. You could perhaps create `/storage/emulated/0/pictures/receipts/tessdata/eng.trainededdata`.

Comment: Sorry @CommonsWare, I don't understand what you mean?

Comment: That is the exact path I have eng.traineddata copying to.

Comment: You are only copying the file if the directory Receipts does not yet exist.

Comment: dataPath does not contain subdir Receipts so outFile is invalid.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion with the folders but the creation of folders was correct, it was the moving of eng.traineddata to the tessdata folder. I fixed the issue by initializing the input and output stream inside the "try" statement and adding if(filename.contains(".traindeddata")) inside the forloop  for(String filename:files).